# In LibGDX scene2d, after changing the items of a selectbox, it no longer has a default listener

Tags: java, user-interface, libgdx, widget, scene2d

I dont think my problem is that hard to solve but I have been searching for a while and cant figure it out.

I have two scene2d `SelectBox` widgets one above the other, in a table, on a stage. Let's call them A and B. Whatever is selected in A determines which list is shown in B. I implement this using a `ChangeListener` on A and all works fine (this isn't the problem).

However, my list A was getting extremely long (500+ items) so I wanted to add a `TextField` above it which would search and match the strings, replacing the old list of A with a shorter one, making it much easier to find what you are looking for. This works fine, I use a `ChangeListener` on the textfield to get the string, compare it to a main list of strings using a for loop and use `aList.setItems();` to add the adjusted string to the `SelectBox`. The list displays (without a click, so I use `aList.showList();` in the `ChangeListener` of the `TextField`) and I think this is where the problem occurs - instead of a click, `showList()` is called from elsewhere. Lets say I change my mind and want to select a different item from A, it will no longer drop down the menu on click. Yet if I change the text which is in the search bar, it displays the list. When the list is displayed, I can click an item and it hides as normal.

This might seems a bit confusing, so here is the code (edited for clarity, so if something is missing let me know)

```
SelectBox aSelect, bSelect;
TextField searchBar;
Stage stage;
Table table;
Skin skin;

ArrayList<String> completeAList;
ArrayList<String> abrevAList;

public chooseItemScreen()
{
    stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());
    skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("uiskin.json"));
    table = new Table();
    table.setFillparent(true);

    completeAList = new ArrayList<String>;
    abrevAList = new ArrayList<String>;

    aSelect = new SelectBox(skin);
    //ItemList is a class with the list of strings as a static method
    completeAList = ItemList.getAList();
    aSelect.setItems(completeAList.toArray());

    //bSelect omitted as is same as A
    //aSelect changeListener also omitted as it is working fine

    searchBar = new TextField("", skin);
    searchBar.setMessageText("SEARCH LIST");

    searchPokemon.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
            updateASelect();
        }
    });

    table.add(searchBar);
    table.row();
    table.add(aList);

    stage.addActor(table);

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

}

private void updateAList()
{
    abrevAList.clear();
    aSelect.clearItems();
    aSelect.hideList()

    for (String string: completeAList)
    {
        if (string.toLowerCase().startsWith(searchBar.getText().toLowerCase()))
        {
            abrevAList.add(string);
        }
    }

    if (abrevAList.isEmpty())
    {
        abrevAList.add("NOT FOUND");
    }

    aSelect.setItems(abrevAList.toArray());

    //It's at this point where I am no longer to click on aSelect
    //I can still select an item from the drop down list, closing the list
    //it's just I can't show list by clicking on the widget after that

    aSelect.showList();
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl20.glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
    Gdx.gl20.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    stage.act();
    stage.draw();

}
```

I added the following listener to tell if the selectBox was being clicked (which it was). I gave all actors names

```
    stage.getRoot().addCaptureListener(new InputListener() {
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            System.out.println(event.getTarget().getName());
            return false;
        }
    });
```

The click is recognised, just the list doesn't show. In my opinion, it is a problem with calling `showList()` and changing the list at the same time.

Any help is appreciated, and if you need more code or any other information, let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a fixed size to the selectbox when adding it to the table, something like

```
table.add(selectBox).width(someValue);
```

or

```
table.add(selectBox).growX();
```

Also, after reviewing your code, I suggest you to remove

```
    aSelect.clearItems();
    aSelect.hideList();
```

And make ArrayList be just libgdx Array< String>, it will make things easier, wont cause allocation when iterating with ':' and you wont need .toArray() when setting the items of your selectboxes. You also can set SelectBox type with SelectBox< String>, and, you can add a row in the same line with table.add(something).row().

After changing the size of the selectbox cell your code worked just fine in my side.

Comment: I think it was the clearItems part which was causing the problems, I just assumed the list would have to be cleared before updating. I removed that and everything works fine, I already had a width I just forgot to include the code. Thank you for your help. Thanks as well for the tip about the libgdx Array class, I didnt even know there was one.

Comment: Yeah, glad to help, libGDX is a HUGE framework, Im using it for about 4 years, and still there are a lot of things to learn